# visual studio compile error after moving solution

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I feel like there is something obvious I'm missing here, but I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution that I moved (into a subdirectory). I delete all the .suo files, but everytime I try and compile the solution (or any individual project), I get the following error: `The operation could not be completed. The parameter is incorrect.`. Moving the solution back to the original directory corrects this, and the solution compiles.

I've moved solution directories before, so I'm unsure why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Are there references to files that weren't moved but relative paths using the `..` may now need to be updated?

Comment: open `.sln` file in `notepad` and try to resolve the paths if any

Comment: Are you using source control? Try changing your working directory and checking out fresh.

Comment: There were some reference paths that were hard coded, so I fixed those, but it didn't help. I then unloaded every project and reloaded them, one by one. That worked for the .NET projects. There are a few unmanaged C++ projects that on trying to compile, give me the error: `The project file '' has been renamed or is no longer in the solution.`

Comment: Please consider trying to raise the visibility of this problem with Microsoft. See https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/9561930-improve-the-the-parameter-is-incorrect-feature